# Подключение скрипта с проверкой на зону домена

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript

У сайта есть 2 домена в зонах .ru и .рф (оба сайта в одной директории). Есть скрипт подключающий кнопку "Мне нравится" от соцсети Вконтакте. Как подключить два скрипта с разными ApiId для разных зон? При одновременном подключении срабатывает только последний. Скрипт имеет такой вид:

```
<script type="text/javascript">VK.init({apiId: (apiId 1-го домена), onlyWidgets: true});</script>
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ который пришёл в голову это проверять вот так:

```
 if( window.location.host.indexOf('ru') != -1 ) {
    //подключаем скрипт для .ru
 } else {
    //иначе для .рф
 }
```